# Way to extract values from data structure

Tags: python

I have a big set of data formatted likely in this way:

```
data=[
  (a1,b1,[(alfa,1,2,3),(alfa,4,5,6),(alfa,1,4,6),(gamma,2,4,3),(gamma,31,4,6),(delta,3,3,4),(alfa,2,4,6)]),
  (a1,b2,[(beta,4,2,6),(beta,1,5,5),(theta,1,0,6)]),
  ........,
  ........
  ]
```

i'm trying to extract from `data` recursively the `"alfa", beta gamma, theta`like a kind of index/referral and the rest of more internal tuple recombined as a matrix (list of list) thus obtained by epurate from their 1st element (the new index). The outer elements `a1,b1,b2` are easy to manipulate and will take part for further manipulations. Need something like :

```
'a1' 'b1' 'alfa' [[1,2,3]
                  [4,5,6]
                  [1,4,6]
                  [2,4,6]]
         'gamma' [[2,4,3]
                  [31,4,6]]
         'delta' [[3,3,4]]
'a1' 'b2' 'beta' [[4,2,6]
                  [1,5,5]]
         'theta' [[1,0,6]]
```

I was using thinking to create many keys of a dict, as per the indexes (the `alfa,beta` or whater I will find) and populate a referred list to each of the keys by append(). here what I've made:

```
tmp ={}
data = []
for i in market:
    for j in i[2]:
        tmp[j[0]]=data.append([j[1],j[2],j[3]])
```

..but the new index tmp[j[0]] will ereditate the whole old values of other indices..or doesn't work

Comment: `append()` modifies the list in place, it doesn't return anything. So you're setting everything in `tmp` to `None`.

Comment: BTW you can use `j[1:]` to get all the elements of `j` except `j[0]`

Comment: It's not clear what your desired result is. You show `a1`, `b1`, and `alfa` in the same row, but not in the format of any Python data structure.

Comment: What is `market`? Is it the same as `data` in the top snippet?

Comment: ..I've made little confusion: market is my data structure to extract, while data and tmp the variables..

Comment: no is not in python format, is a pseudo-code just to show the gerarchie of the market's data

Comment: Use the `edit` link to fix the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
data = [
  ('a1','b1',[('alfa',1,2,3),('alfa',4,5,6),('alfa',1,4,6),('gamma',2,4,3),('gamma',31,4,6),('delta',3,3,4),('alfa',2,4,6)]),
  ('a1','b2',[('beta',4,2,6),('beta',1,5,5),('theta',1,0,6)]),
# and so on...
]
```

You want to convert this into a dictionary, where the keys are three-element tuples and the values are matrices.

Recognize that each `item` in this list is a *tuple*.

- In this item, the first two elements `item[0:2]` are the first two elements of the key you want to use in your dictionary.
- The third element `item[2]` is a list. Each element of *this list* is a tuple, containing:

  1. The first element `elem[0]` is the third element of the key
  2. The remaining elements `elem[1:]` give you a new row in your matrix

So from every `elem` you encounter in `item[2]`, you need to extract the first item to create the key you are looking for in your dict. Then, check if the key already exists in the dict. If it doesn't, create a new list with `row` as its first element. If it does, then simply `.append()` the new row to the list.

```
dict_data = {}

for item in data:
    k1, k2 = item[0:2]
    for elem in item[2]:
        k3 = elem[0]
        row = elem[1:]
        if (k1, k2, k3) in dict_data:
            dict_data[k1, k2, k3].append(row) # or .append(list(row))
        else:
            dict_data[k1, k2, k3] = [row] # or [list(row)]
```

Which gives the following `dict_data`:

```
{('a1', 'b1', 'alfa'): [
                        (1, 2, 3), 
                        (4, 5, 6), 
                        (1, 4, 6),
                        (2, 4, 6)
                       ],
 ('a1', 'b1', 'gamma'): [
                         (2, 4, 3),
                         (31, 4, 6)
                        ],
 ('a1', 'b1', 'delta'): [(3, 3, 4)],
 ('a1', 'b2', 'beta'): [(4, 2, 6), (1, 5, 5)],
 ('a1', 'b2', 'theta'): [(1, 0, 6)]}
```

If you want rows to be lists rather than tuples, simply convert them before adding them (as shown by the comments in the code above)